# does multicolinearity affect classification models? any type of classification models like SVM, ANN, Random Forest,etc

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, multi-class

I have been working on a dataset with more than 50 variables and I know some of the variables are highly correlated(>0.8). so for my multi-class classification problem  should I worry about multicolinearity?

Comment: Hi and welcome to CV. In your question something central is missing, which is: what are you trying to do? It all depends on what you want to achieve with your method.

Comment: i am trying to do multi-class classification and want to achieve high accuracy